# Multiply value with specific columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to multiply a value (0.045) with specific columns (that start with "i") in a dataset. There is also a column called "id" that has the value 0.045 in all rows.

I've tried this, which did not work:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("i")), ~.id)
```

The columns to be multiplied can be specified based on position or based on the fact that they all start with "i"

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Magnus

Comment: You lose a `*` symbol. In addition, the formula part should be an argument of `across()`, not that of `mutate()`. You put it to the wrong place. Try `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("i"), ~ . * id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I used `iris` dataset in order to create the example. Be careful that the new definition for mutating the columns should be inside `across()` and not outside it, as you have in the shared code. Here the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
iris %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~.*0.045))
```

Output (some rows):

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1         0.2295      0.1575          1.4         0.2     setosa
2         0.2205      0.1350          1.4         0.2     setosa
3         0.2115      0.1440          1.3         0.2     setosa
4         0.2070      0.1395          1.5         0.2     setosa
5         0.2250      0.1620          1.4         0.2     setosa
6         0.2430      0.1755          1.7         0.4     setosa
7         0.2070      0.1530          1.4         0.3     setosa
8         0.2250      0.1530          1.5         0.2     setosa
9         0.1980      0.1305          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
cols_bool <- startsWith(names(iris), "Sepal")
cbind(iris[,!cols_bool, drop = FALSE], iris[,cols_bool, drop = FALSE] * 0.045)
```